# Firebase: Database Authentication error

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I have configured my Android app to login to the firebase and it does with no issues.
I have create login activity and after successful login I am moving on to a new activity.
Later on in one of my AsyncTask I am query the Database
I have changed the permission rules so only authenticate users will be able to read/write...
But I am still getting permission denied even after successful login.

Do I need to put the UID somewhere in the query ?

Here is one of my queries:

```
Query personFaceSizeHeightQueryEndAt = myRef.orderByChild("mCalculateFaceSizeHeight")
                .endAt(faceDetails.getmCalculateFaceSizeHeight())
                .limitToLast(1);
        personFaceSizeHeightQueryEndAt.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                    String personName = dataSnapshot.getKey();
                    Log.d(TAG, "personFaceSizeHeightQueryEndAt:onChildAdded:" + personName);
                    if( checkIfPersonAlreadyFoundInQueryFaceSizeHeight(personName) == false){
                        Person person  = dataSnapshot.getValue(Person.class);
                        checkNumberOfMatchesAndWriteToTheDisk(personName,person);
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                if(dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "personFaceSizeHeightQueryEndAt:onChildChanged:" + dataSnapshot.getKey());

                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                if(dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "personFaceSizeHeightQueryEndAt:onChildRemoved:" + dataSnapshot.getKey());
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                if(dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "personFaceSizeHeightQueryEndAt:onChildMoved:" + dataSnapshot.getKey());
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                Log.d(TAG, "personFaceSizeHeightQueryEndAt:DatabaseError:" + databaseError.getMessage());

            }
        });
    }
```

Here is the message from the login activity when successful login

```
07-20 06:39:31.050 4806-4806/com.example.erang.facerecognition D/EmailPassword: signInWithEmail:success
```

Here are my DataBase rules:

```
{
  "rules": {
      "People": {
        "users": {
      "$uid": {
        ".read": "auth.uid === $uid",
        ".write": "auth.uid === $uid"
      }
    Later there are the indexes ...
```

Comment: I am getting DefaultFirebaseUser :
com.google.firebase.auth.internal.DefaultFirebaseUser
When running 
    FirebaseUser mUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
from the query task
Not my user...

Comment: I believe this is the answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39992744/firebase-link-user-authentication-to-another-activity

Comment: I have the UID it is my uid, so I am not sure why I am getting access deny

Answer (score 0):

You close your emulator and run again .